# "A ribattone": che cosa significa?

Tags: meaning

Nella versione in italiano dell'episodio *Il miracolo delle nozze di Cana* di *Mistero buffo*, di Dario Fo, ho letto:

> E tutti che tracannavano, si ubriacavano, ballavano, ballava la sposa, cantava lo sposo. Il padre della sposa, davanti a un muro, dava testate **a ribattone**, cattivo... che nessuno lo aveva avvertito del miracolo!

Non capisco il significato dell'espressione "a ribattone" in questo passaggio. Ho cercato il vocabolo "ribattone", ma non l'ho trovato in nessun dizionario. Si tratta di un termine di origine dialettale? Sapreste spiegarmi cosa significa "a ribattone"?

Answer (score 2):

Dal momento che il verbo "Ribàttere" significa *"Battere di nuovo, anche più volte, ripetutamente"*, mi immagino che l'espressione "a ribattone" indichi in qualche modo una serie ripetuta e violenta di testate contro il muro (il suffisso "-one" si usa come accrescitivo e in questo caso potrebbe appunto servire a indicare che le testate erano particolarmente forti).

Nota che esiste anche il sostantivo *"ribattino"* (o *"rivetto"*) che indica un tipo di chiodo (http://www.treccani.it/vocabolario/ribattino/)

Non saprei se l'espressione è gergale o dialettale, oppure un termine di pura invenzione dell'autore.